Animals in the Ark of Noach: a metaphor for the nations of the world
In Parshas Noach (Bereishis 6:19-20), we read the instruction G-d gave Noach to build an ark, and together with his family, to put in animals:

וּמִכׇּל־הָ֠חַ֠י מִֽכׇּל־בָּשָׂ֞ר שְׁנַ֧יִם מִכֹּ֛ל תָּבִ֥יא אֶל־הַתֵּבָ֖ה לְהַחֲיֹ֣ת אִתָּ֑ךְ זָכָ֥ר וּנְקֵבָ֖ה יִֽהְיֽוּ׃
מֵהָע֣וֹף לְמִינֵ֗הוּ וּמִן־הַבְּהֵמָה֙ לְמִינָ֔הּ מִכֹּ֛ל רֶ֥מֶשׂ הָֽאֲדָמָ֖ה לְמִינֵ֑הוּ שְׁנַ֧יִם מִכֹּ֛ל יָבֹ֥אוּ אֵלֶ֖יךָ לְהַֽחֲיֽוֹת
And of every living thing of all flesh, two of every sort shalt thou bring into the ark, to keep them alive with thee; they shall be male and female.
Of birds after their kind, and of cattle after their kind, of every creeping thing of the earth after its kind, two of every sort shall come to thee, to keep them alive.

There are different meforshim who explain that the term "creeping things" or "wild animals" refer to the אומות העולם הרשעים (wicked amongst the gentile nations) (see for example the Ibn Ezra on Yeshayahu 56:9):

All ye beasts of the field, etc. The idea connecting the following with the preceding verses is, that the righteous Israelites and the proselytes will return, but those that persevere in the worship of idols will not return. אתיו Come. It is imperative (comp. 21:12) of אתה to come; comp. ואתה, and He came (Deut. 33:2). God summons the idolatrous wicked nations, to come and devour the wicked of Israel, like wild beasts that devour each other.

On the peshat-level, we can explain that the reason why G-d instructed Noach to bring in these animals, was in order to preserve them, so that they, after the flood, could "start anew". However, I was looking for an explanation based on the Ibn Ezra on Yeshayahu 56:9, where he seems to explains that "wild animals" refer to the wicked amongst the nations. Maybe G-d wanted that Noach would bring them in, so that, during the stay on the ark, they would be educated to be "a mensch"? (as per the Meshech Chochma's explanation mentioned here)

I could understand if all the animals are the goyim and the people are the Jews. But apart from appreciating the "beauty" of the Greeks, I have never seen a Jewish source describing any non Jewish nation as good. Are the people God and the clean animals the Jews in this metaphor?

“Clean animals the Jews” that could work I suppose.

It's in your quote: God summons the idolatrous wicked nations, to come and devour the wicked of Israel

@shmosel I don't see how that tries to answer my question. That quotes proves that the evil amongst the nations can be referred to as wild animals. But that was not the question though.

It tells you what purpose they serve

@shmosel yes, but the premise was that the wild animals in the ark was metaphorical for the nations

I guess I'm not understanding your question.

The metaphore is usually a tool to answer a specific question or address a difficulty. Your idea elegantly helps explain how all nations could live together inside the city of Bavel united by a common cause by modeling the survival in the Noach's Ark. However, it would be good to derive lessons from this analogy. Thank you.

@shmosel: in the episode of the ark, the Torah says that there were wild animals. In Yeshayahu, with Ibn Ezra, it says that the wild animals refer to the (wicked) nations of the world. Based on this, could it be that it metaphorically speaks about the nations of the world that were being saved from the flood? E.g. the nations of the world that, during the 120 years, came to Noach and came to realise that they needed to repent, and thus were on the ark.
